# Android: Default XML Editor isn't opening anymore [Unsupported Content Type Error]

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, android-xml

I've been using Eclipse for developing apps in android for quite some time. I updated the Android SDK Platform to 3.0, API 11 recently. Now I'm unable to open the AndroidManifest.xml or any other XML files in the Layout folder by double clicking.

When I double click any XML file (like main.xml / strings.xml), I get the "Unsupported Content Type" error. 
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/67e93ddb8a.png

Is there any way to solve this problem?

P.S: If I open the xml files with "Open With -> Text Editor", it is opening, but I'm unable to see the layout for main.xml and respective GUI for strings.xml and androidmanifest.xml
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f537965b68.png

Comment: @Basiclife As per the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), Stack Overflow questions can relate to "software tools commonly used by programmers", so this seems a perfect fit here.

Answer (score 7):

If you have installed `ArgoEclipse UMLEditor`, Uninstall it.

> Eclipse >> Help >> About Eclipse >> Installation Details >> select >> Unistall

I had this issue too.
 There is a bug in UMLEditor, 
[Someone file a Bug on this issue, if you are a member at Tigris.org](http://argouml.tigris.org/issues/enter_bug.cgi?issue_type=DEFECT&component=argouml)

[image: AgroEclipse UMLEditor Bug]

Answer (score 4):

An inconvenient fix at the moment is to:

> rename the file then rename it back

Sorry if you have 100's of XML files! :-(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem that I could not open Eclipse Plug-in development .xml files after I had installed the Android ADT plugin. It insisted on using the Android Common XML Editor for all .xml files, even those not relating to Android development.

To open the .xml file in another editor I right click on the .xml file and choose 'Open With...' and select "Plug-in Manifest Editor" which is what I wanted in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try just to get out of the problem for now renaming the AndroidManifest.xml and 
also, i suggest you should subscribe to [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15003) in google code to know about how the Android Team is going with these problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed anything else that might have changed what Eclipse thinks the content of those files is, i.e. from XML to something else?  Right-click on a file and bring up its Properties dialog; the Resource page will indicate what Type of file it's considered to be.  The XML Editor expects it to be one of the types under the Text/XML part of the tree in the Content Types preference page.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem just yesterday. I looked around many sites with no answer. Then, I remebered that I have many XML editors that are installed on my Eclipse as a plugins. I think of Google Apps Engine, Tomcat ... Then I sais : maybe it's because of those plugins. So, I unzipped a new eclipse in a subdir, I download the ADT and everything just worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, following steps worked for me -
Open Window > Preferences > General > Content Types
Select "Text"
Under "File associations"
Select *.xml
Click remove button on right side and then ok in bottom

Answer (score 0):

I'm using some software that uses `*.xml.templ` files for configuration (which is an annoying use of XML in the first place), then copies them to `*.xml` files for its actual use. I tried adding the extension `*.xml.templ` in Preferences>General>Content Types>Text>XML, thinking that Bash-like filename completion would be used. This seemed to be ignored--no matter how many times I closed and reopended the editor/the perspective/Eclipse itself, it always complained about an unsupported content-type and then opened the file in the XML editor without any highlighting.

Instead, I had to add `*.templ` instead. Apparently extensions can't include periods?