# Eclipse running on Linux doesn't autocomplete Android XML

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, adt

Just recently, my Android XML files which define my layout and etc have stopped autocompleting. When I type `android:` I used to get a list of options related to Android such as `layout_width`, etc. Now I get only four options, the first being `xmlns="default namespace"`

Also the tab to change to the layout designer and other tabs are gone, I am left with a 'design' tab which shows my XML structure and a 'source' tab with the actual XML. I think they are being recognised as normal XML files rather than Android XML files, is there a way to change this?

I am running **Eclipse Indigo Version 3.7.0** with the **ADT plugin Version 15.0.1**.

Here is an example of one of the XML files it isn't working in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:textSize="16dp"
          android:background="#FFFFFF"
          android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>
```

Comment: Try restarting Eclipse, it helped me out from time to time. Also, a clean build of the project might help. If all fails, reinstall ADT.

Comment: Restarted and cleaned my build to no avail, I'll try reinstalling the ADT

Comment: Reinstalled the ADT and it's still not working, has something to do with the default file editor being chosen for XML files

Comment: One inconvienient fix for this problem is renaming the XML files somehow it changes what the default file editor will be i.e. instead of XML default Editor it will open the Android Layout editor.

[This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123370/android-default-xml-editor-isnt-opening-anymore-unsupported-content-type-erro) documents the same fix, as the answer.

Comment: They can even just be moved and then moved back and they'll work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to a new workspace may help.